# Restore an android system that will access my google account

Tags: root-access

Hi I bought my tablet in China but they have blocked access to my get to my google account. How can I install the core component that allows me to access my google account and download apps from the playstore?

Answer (score 0):

Android devices made for Chinese market don't have Google apps installed. You need to download GAPPS packages and flash it (from recovery).
Download link : [Open GAPPS](http://opengapps.org/)

Download the one that matches your android version.